# Why is jQuery each not going through all JSON items from two functions using $.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

The json returns from the two ajax functions seem to download complete when I check with Chrome Network inspector.  However the jQuery each is not going through all items of both json files. It only goes through the first three items of the json files. So that jQuery each only builds the movie titles of the first three movies.

If I use $.when with only one function it works and returns all items.
I commented out the two areas that work as a single function.

jquery 1.11.0

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var movieCollectionUrl = 'json/movie_collection.json';
    var movieFavoritesUrl = 'json/movie_favorites.json';
    var movieCollectionElement = $('#collection ul');
    var movieFavoritesElement = $('#favorites ul');

    function getList(url)
    {
        return $.ajax(
        {
            dataType: "json",
            type: "get",
            url: url
        });
    }

    function buildList(data, element)
    {
        $.each(data, function(i)
        {
            var title = data[0][i].title; 
            //var title = data[i].title; //this returns all items but only with a single function with $.when
            var html = '<li>' + title + '</li>';
            element.append(html);
        });
    }


    function myExecute(movieCollectionData, movieFavoritesData)
    {
        buildList(movieCollectionData, movieCollectionElement);
        buildList(movieFavoritesData, movieFavoritesElement);
    }

    /*
    function executeSingle(movieFavoritesData)
    {
        buildList(movieFavoritesData, movieFavoritesElement);
    }
    */

    function myFail()
    {
        alert("FAILED TO LOAD");
    }

    $.when(getList(movieCollectionUrl), getList(movieFavoritesUrl)).then(myExecute, myFail);
    //$.when(getList(movieFavoritesUrl)).then(executeSingle, myFail); //This one works. Using only one function here
}); //document ready
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
        <title>Movies</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="favorites">
            <h2>Favorite Movies</h2>
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
        <div id="collection">
            <h2>Movie Collection</h2>
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

movie_collection.json

```
[
{
    "title": "127 Hours",
    "poster": "http://slurm.trakt.us/images/posters_movies/6646.1.jpg"
},
{
    "title": "2012",
    "poster": "http://slurm.trakt.us/images/posters_movies/463.jpg"
},
{
    "title": "The 40 Year Old Virgin",
    "poster": "http://slurm.trakt.us/images/posters_movies/658.1.jpg"
},
{
    "title": "A Better Life",
    "poster": "http://slurm.trakt.us/images/posters_movies/182444.1.jpg"
},
{
    "title": "A Moment To Remember",
    "poster": "http://slurm.trakt.us/images/posters_movies/162086.jpg"
}]
```

movie_favorites.json

```
[
{
    "title": "A Seperation",
    "poster": "http://slurm.trakt.us/images/posters_movies/176861.2.jpg"
},
{
    "title": "Abraham Lincoln Vampire Hunter",
    "poster": "http://slurm.trakt.us/images/posters_movies/184657.2.jpg"
},
{
    "title": "The Adventures of Tin Tin",
    "poster": "http://slurm.trakt.us/images/posters_movies/13066.2.jpg"
},
{
    "title": "Agore",
    "poster": "http://slurm.trakt.us/images/posters_movies/223.jpg"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the example of `$.when` in the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```

As explained, the arguments passed to the callback function are **arrays** of the form `[ data, statusText, jqXHR ]`. The first element of the arrays contains the actual response. So you have to change your function to

```
function myExecute(movieCollectionData, movieFavoritesData)
{
    buildList(movieCollectionData[0], movieCollectionElement);
    buildList(movieFavoritesData[0], movieFavoritesElement);
}
```

---

The single case works because `$.when` doesn't create a new promise, it simply returns the one that `$.ajax` returns, so it doesn't aggregate the results of multiple promises.

Comment: @FelixKing Thank you. I did read over that but I guess I figured since I was getting three items that the [0] I had in the ajax function was enough.  Your answer was right though and I also had to take out the [0] on the ajax function.  Thank you very much

Comment: Any explanation why I was getting three items for each json file though? I mean it should have it either worked or not worked at all

Comment: Because the array has three elements, `[ data, statusText, jqXHR ]`. You iterated over those three elements with `data` in `$.each(data, function(i)` but you are accessing `data[0][i]`. Since `i` only ranged from `0` to `2`, you only rendered the first three items in the list. Alternatively to my suggestions, you could also change the loop to `$.each(data[0], ...)`.

Comment: That makes sense to me. That will help me avoid this in the future. Thanks for the concise explanation. And yes your alternative way works well too. I think I'll keep the first suggestion as it will help me remember the why better.